# Iterate through two Lists with condition

Tags: java, list

Problem:

I have two sorted by a `property` Lists with different length. I need to create two resulting Lists with a defined records count and sorted by the `property`. There should be a condition in a loop block to verify which record should be added to the resulting list.

For example, two lists sorted by `date` property in `DESC` order:

```
list1: [{'1', '13:45:55', 'List1Title1'}, {'2', '13:40:50', 'List1Title2'}]

list2: [{'1', '13:50:55', 'List2Title1'}, {'2', '13:35:50', 'List2Title2'}]
```

For count = 3, result should look like:

```
resultList1: [{'1', '13:45:55', 'List1Title1'}, {'2', '13:40:50', 'List1Title2'}]

resultList2: [{'1', '13:50:55', 'List2Title1'}]
```

I've tried to iterate through Lists with help of the `for...` with known loops count:

```
List<Tx> list1 = ...;
List<Tx> list2 = ...;
int list1Index = 0;
int list2Index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  if (list1.get(list1Index).getDate() > list2.get(list2Index).getDate()) {
      resultList1.add(list1.get(list1Index));
      ++list1Index;
    } else {
      resultList2.add(list2.get(list2Index));
      ++list2Index;
    }
}
```

But this implementation isn't save for cases when lists have a different size or even are empty.

Is there a possibility to iterate over these two Lists without a large amount of `if/elseif` blocks?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I'm sure I see an error in your code.  `list1Index` and `list2Index` are equal to 0 on each iteration. These variables are incremented but then reset to 0 in the beginning of the next iteration.

Comment: @naXa, thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop until `selected == count` or both `list1` and `list2` have been traversed.

In the loop,

- If `list1` or `list2` has been traversed, then just consider the left
  one.
- If not, compare them and determine which index should be incremented.

  ```
  int selected = 0;

  for (int list1Index = 0, list2Index = 0;
       selected < count && (list1Index < list1.size() || list2Index < list2.size());
       selected++) {
      if (list1Index == list1.size()) {
          resultList2.add(list2.get(list2Index));
          list2Index++;
      } else if (list2Index == list2.size()) {
          resultList1.add(list1.get(list1Index));
          list1Index++;
      } else if (list1.get(list1Index).getDate() > list2.get(list2Index).getDate()) {
          resultList1.add(list1.get(list1Index));
          list1Index++;
      } else {
          resultList2.add(list2.get(list2Index));
          list2Index++;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the `for` condition check if the there are any more elements in the list

```
for (int i = 0; i < count && i < list1.size() && i < list2.size(); i++) {
    \\ code here
}
```

And add two more for loop to handle the leftovers

```
for (int i = 0; i < count && i < list1.size(); i++) {
    resultList1.add(list1.get(list1Index));
    ++list1Index;
}

for (int i = 0; i < count && i < list2.size(); i++) {
    resultList2.add(list2.get(list2Index));
    ++list2Index;
}
```

Those loops will be executed only if there are any elements left.